# Using random.choice for discord.py within embed

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am not sure if this is the correct code, but I am trying to return a random rating when an user types the command "?rating". I have created a variable_list containing the rating numbers that the bot is supposed to return. But I am also using embed. And I am not able to get the random.choice working inside the embed.

```py
@client.command()
async def rating(ctx, *):
    variable_list = [
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
    ]

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=0xc81f9f,
        title="Rating",
        description=f"{ctx.author.mention} (random.choice(variable_list)) is your rating"
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.message.guild.name}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You need to wrap your `random.choice(variable_list)` in braces just like you did with `ctx.author.mention`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment of **Lukas Tahler** here is the answer:

Since you want to select something from a list here, you must bracket or mark the function with `{}`.
So your description only needs the following:

```py
description=f"{ctx.author.mention} {random.choice(variable_list)} is your rating" # Added {}
```

Otherwise your `random.choice(variable_list)` will only be seen as a kind of a comment/text output and not as an "inner function".

Answer (score 0):

As @Lukas Thaler pointed out, just use curly braces.

```py
@client.command()
async def rating(ctx, *):
    variable_list = [
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
    ]

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=0xc81f9f,
        title="Rating",
        description=f"{ctx.author.mention} {random.choice(variable_list)} is your rating"
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.message.guild.name}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: The extra string conversion of the randomly chosen element is not necessary - Python will do that on it's own when assembling the f-string

Comment: It still works, but I guess it wouldn't hurt to edit it.